# Accessing first element of a sorted nested list for second smallest second element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a nested linked list:

```
list_a = [[A, 12.1], [B, 15.6], [C, 9.8], [D, 12.1], [F, 96.3]]
```

I have sorted the list successfully using `sorted(list_a)`, according to the second elements of the sub-lists. How do I get output A and D(first-elements of the list with second-smallest second-elements)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full sort is unnecessary here. You can use [`heap.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) followed by a list comprehension:

```
from heapq import nsmallest
from operator import itemgetter

list_a = [['A', 12.1], ['B', 15.6], ['C', 9.8], ['D', 12.1], ['F', 96.3]]

second_largest_val = nsmallest(2, map(itemgetter(1), list_a))[1]
res = [key for key, val in list_a if val == second_largest_val]

# ['A', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following conditional [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_a = [['A', 12.1], ['B', 15.6], ['C', 9.8], ['D', 12.1], ['F', 96.3]]
sorted_a = sorted(list_a, key=lambda x: x[1])
[x for x, y in sorted_a if y == sorted_a[1][1]]
# ['A', 'D']
```

This does however check `float` objects for equality which [is not ideal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python). So you might want to resort to using [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) which is available in Python >= 3.5:

```
from math import isclose
[x for x, y in sorted_a if isclose(y, sorted_a[1][1])]
# ['A', 'D']
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does isclose(y, sorted_a[1][1]) do? More specifically, does sorted_a[1][1] refer to the second element of second sub_list specifically? If so, how do we encounter more than one least second-elements..

Comment: I linked the docs to `isclose` in the answer. Since floats suffer from precision issues, this function allows you to assert approximate equality. `sorted_a[1][1] ` does refer to the second element of second sub_list (`12.1`) and the comprehension collects all first elements that this very second element.